# correct and efficient way to flatten array in numpy in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have:

```
a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

and I'd like to flatten it, joining the two inner lists into one flat array entry. I can do:

```
array(list(flatten(a)))
```

but that seems inefficient due to the list cast (I want to end up with an array and not a generator.)

Also, how can this be generalized to an array like this:

```
b = array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]])
```

where the result should be:

```
b = array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
           [10,11,12,13,14,15]])
```

are there builtin/efficient numpy/scipy operators for this? thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`reshape` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> b = numpy.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]])
>>> b.reshape([2, 6])
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: I think it should be `a.reshape([2,6])`, thanks!

Comment: @user248237: uh, sorry, I misread your question, still it's that method you have to use. Fixed now. :)

Comment: reshape() is a good method.

Comment: And if you're lazy like me you can do `b.reshape([2, -1])`

Answer (score 43):

You might need to check out `numpy.flatten` and `numpy.ravel`, both return a 1-d array from an n-d array.

Furthermore, if you're not going to modify the returned 1-d array, I suggest you use `numpy.ravel`, since it doesn't make a copy of the array, but just return a view of the array, which is much faster than `numpy.flatten`.

```
>>>a = np.arange(10000).reshape((100,100))

>>>%timeit a.flatten()
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.02 µs per loop

>>>%timeit a.ravel()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 412 ns per loop
```

Also check out this [post](http://cyrille.rossant.net/numpy-performance-tricks/).

Comment: I had to look it up: micro = 10^-6, nano=10^-9

Comment: A view is not always better and if you are not careful remembering it is a view it can lead to bugs - do this only if it makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.arange(1,7).reshape((2,3))
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

and

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b=np.arange(1,13).reshape((2,2,3))
>>> b
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
>>> b.reshape((2,6))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: +1 for flatten() -- it can also do Fortran/column-major flattening. reshape(-1) will also flatten.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = np.arange(10000)

%timeit a.reshape(100,100)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 517 ns per loop

%timeit a.resize(100,100)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 428 ns per loop
```

I wonder reshape should take far lesser time but its almost similar